# How to animate items when navigating to page Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I would love to animate the very first display of page after navigating to it ..

this is my working code:
https://jsfiddle.net/uLhzqxg9/68/

html:

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app dark>
    <div class="box" justify="center" align="center">
      <div v-for="item in list" :key="item.id">
        <transition name="view" appear>
          <div class="card">{{item.name}}</div>
        </transition>
      </div>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

vue:

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify);

var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
  },
  data: {
    list: [
    {id: 1, name: "Lorem"},
    {id: 2, name: "Ipsum"},
    {id: 3, name: "Dolor"},
    {id: 4, name: "Sit"},
    {id: 5, name: "Amet"},
    {id: 5, name: "Amet"}
    ]
  }
});
```

css:

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.box .card  {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

but it doesn't do anything ... would you know why?

this is an example of what I would love to achieve ... when you open the link, the images slide in from the left side ....
[Example animation on load](https://themes.themegoods.com/photome/demo/gallery-archive/gallery-archive-4-columns-wide/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rendered list items should be wrapped by the `transition-group` component that can take a tag name with html element and it can also take other attribute such as `class`, `style` and `justify` ...
Based on this [example](https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/YLmdxz) I tried to simulate the desired behavior using CSS variables and calculated transition values.

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app dark>
      <transition-group name="view" appear tag="div" class="box" justify="center" align="center" :style="{ '--total': list.length }" >
        <div v-for="(item,i) in list" :key="item.id" :style="{'--i': i}" v-if="showItems && i < limit" class="view-item">
          <div class="card">{{item.name}}</div>
        </div>
      </transition-group>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.box .card  {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #85a5dd;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid #4525ff;
}

.view-move {
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear, transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.view-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.4s linear, transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.7, 0.4);
  transition-delay: calc(0.1s * (var(--total) - var(--i)));
}
.view-enter-active {
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear, transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.5, 0.1, 1);
  transition-delay: calc(0.1s * var(--i));
}
.view-enter, .view-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
.view-enter {
  transform: translate(-1em,-1em);
}
.view-leave-to {
  transform: translate(1em,1em);
}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      showItems: false,
      list: [
        { id: 1, name: "Lorem" },
        { id: 2, name: "Ipsum" },
        { id: 3, name: "Dolor" },
        { id: 4, name: "Sit" },
        { id: 5, name: "Amet" },
        { id: 6, name: "Amet" }
      ]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    limit() {
      return this.list.length;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.showItems = true;
    });
  }
});
```

**[Live DEMO](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/OJQrdOB)**

Comment: this might be it :)) looks promising .. I will try later in my real project and reward if working ... thx!!

Comment: this answer is not base on vuetify its use vue transition group and css .

Comment: @salehshokouhi this is a valid solution since we're still in vue ecosystem, for example if I used other library like JQuery to make the animation that would be a bad solution

Comment: OK i understand but the question need vuetify solution.

Comment: @salehshokouhi no, it does not **need** a Vuetify solution per-se (nothing saying so in the question at least). OP is using Vuetify, but he doesn't need a Vuetify specific especially if his issue can be solved with vanilla CSS. Usually, using the lowest powerful tool is better (solving an issue with vanilla HTML is better than solving it with JS or even Vue). This applies here too: it works without Vuetify, so it's probably as good even better since it strips the whole dependency on another UI framework. Relying too much on frameworks is not always the best bet if you don't know the basics.

Comment: sorry I haven't had a chance to try .. but it works, obviously :) so I will try later (my real project is a bit more complex than this example but I will figure it out) .. 

marking this as the answer and reward is on the way ... thank you :)

Comment: @Mr.P if you'll have any issue let me know, you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

You should add the items to the list after page load is complete. You may use `setTimeout` for example. Below are snippets based on your code.

I updated my answer and added Vuetify with Vue v2.7 and Vuetify v2.6.

Sample https://jsfiddle.net/shsaleh/L32xjgy4/64/

Vuetify sample https://jsfiddle.net/shsaleh/1k0fzm4b/87/

Vue:

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify);

var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
     this.rlist= this.list 
    }, 500)
  },
  methods: {},
  data: {
    list: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Lorem"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Ipsum"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Dolor"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "Sit"
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: "Amet"
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        name: "Amet"
      }
    ],
    rlist: []
  }
});
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app dark>
    <div>
      <transition-group class="box" justify="center" align="center" name="list" tag="ul">
        <div v-for="item in rlist" :key="item.id">
          <div class="card">{{item.name}}</div>
        </div>
      </transition-group>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

css:

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.box .card {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.list-enter-active,
.list-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

.list-enter,
.list-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(30px);
}
```

#### Update with Vuetify's version

Vue:

```js
//vm.use(Vuetify)
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
    this.loading = false
    }, 500)
  },
  methods: {},
  data: {
  loading:true,
    list: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Lorem"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Ipsum"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Dolor"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "Sit"
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        name: "Amet"
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        name: "Amet"
      } 
    ],
  }
});
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app dark>
      <v-slide-x-transition>
     <div v-show="!loading">
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-center">
          <div class="box  ma-1" v-for="item in list" :key="item.id">
            <div class="card">{{item.name}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
         </div>
      </v-slide-x-transition>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.box .card {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: I've edited your answer with some improvements. Feel free to strip the non Vuetify answer if you feel like it's un-needed here.